# Spring Boot Dandelion Datatables Thymeleaf search between dates

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, datatable, thymeleaf, dandelion

I am Dandelion datatables with Spring Boot and thymeleaf.

This is my code for a table i want to show all logs at.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="expiredUsersTable" dt:table="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th dt:sortInitDirection="desc">TIME</th>
        <th dt:filterable="true" dt:filterType="select">Log Level</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="log : ${logs}">
        <td th:text="${log?.getFormattedDate()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${log?.level}"></td>
        <td th:text="${log?.message}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add filter between date ranges for this table but i could not achieve this with the dandelion datatables. What are the ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In thymeleaf, this would look something like this:

Controller:

```
// Create these dates however you want, these example dates are filtering between 1950 and 1960.
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1950);
model.put("start", gc.getTime());

gc.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1960);
model.put("end", gc.getTime());
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="expiredUsersTable" dt:table="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th dt:sortInitDirection="desc">TIME</th>
            <th dt:filterable="true" dt:filterType="select">Log Level</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="log : ${logs}" th:unless="${log.date.before(start) OR log.date.after(end)}">
            <td th:text="${log?.formattedDate}"></td>
            <td th:text="${log?.level}"></td>
            <td th:text="${log?.message}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Im looking for javascript way of solving this. Sorry forgot to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

The datatable site has examples of range filtering: https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

I'm forced to guess the format of the dates you are using (this example is using dd-mm-yyyy), something like this worked for me:

Html:

```
<body onload="initFilter();">
    From <input type="text" id="start" /> to <input type="text" id="end" />
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    // <![CDATA[
    function parseDate(date) {
        if (date.length < 10)
            return false;

        var parts = date.split("-");
        var d = parseInt(parts[0]);
        var m = parseInt(parts[1]) - 1;
        var y = parseInt(parts[2]);

        return new Date(y, m, d);
    }

    function initFilter() {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
            function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                var start = parseDate($('#start').val());
                var end = parseDate($('#end').val());
                var data = parseDate(data[0]);

                var valid = true;
                valid = valid && (!start || (start.getTime() =< data.getTime()));
                valid = valid && (!end || (end.getTime() > data.getTime()));
                return valid;
            }
        );

        $('#start, #end').keyup( function() {
            oTable_expiredUsersTable.draw();
        });
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
```